# I want to use RNAplot command in Vienna RNA package

Tags: linux

I want to draw RNA secondary structure circular diagram of my RNA dot-bracket notation file.
I already download Vienna RNA by using conda install.
Of course, I already have read RNAplot document.
(https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/RNAfold.1.html)
However I still can not use RNAplot command.

How do I draw RNA secondary structure circular diagram by using RNAplot command in linux.
Your answer would be really helpful.

Thank you.

I want to draw RNA secondary structure circular diagram by using RNAplot command in linux.

Answer (score 0):

To use RNAplot command to draw RNA secondary structure circular diagram in Linux, you can follow these steps:

Open your terminal or command prompt and navigate to the directory where your dot-bracket notation file is located.

Type the following command to generate the PostScript output file for your RNA secondary structure:

RNAplot -o ps <input_file>

Replace <input_file> with the name of your dot-bracket notation file. This command generates a PostScript file called rna.ps in the same directory.

To view the RNA secondary structure circular diagram, you need to convert the PostScript file to a viewable format. You can do this by typing the following command:

ps2pdf rna.ps

This command generates a PDF file called rna.pdf in the same directory.

To view the circular diagram, you can open the PDF file using a PDF viewer such as Adobe Acrobat Reader.
Note: If you want to change the size or color of the circular diagram, you can use the -W and -C options with the RNAplot command. For example, to change the size of the circular diagram to 10cm, you can use the following command:

RNAplot -o ps -W 10 <input_file>

I hope this helps!